# Do I have to click a link in selenium to verify the results or can I just extract the href?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

I'm trying to verify that hyperlinks direct users to the correct page. Instead of clicking the word and checking the URL of the driver, it would be faster to just extract the href of the word and verify it is the correct URL. Would this actually always ensure the user is directed to the correct page, or is it safer to click and then check the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the latter, i.e. click on the hyperlink and ensure it redirects to the expected page. That is how one would do if they have to test it manually.

This will not only imitate human actions but will also increase the confidence of stake holders/paying customers.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the href wouldn't actually check the link is working. The best you can do is verify that the URL is valid. Valid URL (as per [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/urls.html)):

> A URL is a valid URL if at least one of the following conditions holds:
>
> - The URL is a valid URI reference [RFC3986].
> - The URL is a valid IRI reference and it has no query component. [RFC3987]
> - The URL is a valid IRI reference and its query component contains no unescaped non-ASCII characters. [RFC3987]
> - The URL is a valid IRI reference and the character encoding of the URL's Document is UTF-8 or UTF-16. [RFC3987]

Answer (score 0):

I think I will go with first option. A link usually is an a tag in DOM HTML. A tag will always have the natural HREF attribute and it still is clickable no matter what (even your javascript is messed up).

Verify a hyper link by clicking to it and verify the url it redirects to usually is a bad pratice at all. If you do this, you have to deal with the overhead of waiting for page loading and get page url.
You should verify a hyper link by:

- verify it is visible
- verify its href attribute (the more deep verification is sending a HTTP request to this hyper link using href to verify if this link is not dying)

But if a link is another HTML tag rather than an a tag (like a button). You should verify by clicking to it.